# Llamar el value de un button a un input en un modal

Tags: php, javascript

creo que es algo sencillo:
[image: Donde indica la flecha es el value, que al presionar el button se carga un id, deseo que ese mismo id que se carga se almacene en un input que lo explico a continuaciòn]
[image: Quiero que lo que se captura arriba en el button, se almacene en este input, la pregunta es como llamo la variable, para que el mismo dato seleccionado se almacene allí?]
En la imagen numero 1 tengo mi value almacenado un id que se general al dar click en el button, lo que quiero es que ese mismo valor que se almacena en el value llamarlo al value de mi input para que pueda tenerlo dentro de mi model

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! por favor, el codigo debe ir como texto, ya que las imagenes no se visualizan bien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías recoger el valor al clickar el boton con jquery y cargarlo al mismo tiempo en tu input:

```
$("#boton-intervencion").click(function() {
    var aux = $('#btn').val();
    $('input-intervencion').val(aux);
```